# How to bulk move Android apps to the SD card?

Tags: applications, storage, file-management

I have an Android 4.4.3. Currently, all my Android apps are on the phone's internal storage, which is quite low @ 8GB. I've recently installed a 32GB SD card into the phone.

I understand that I can go to Android Application Manager > Apps > click on app > click "Move" (to the SD card). For the several apps I've tried to do this, the "Move" button was grayed out. Only one app I've tried has had the "Move" button enabled.

Is there any way I can bulk-move all Android apps to the SD card?

Comment: Can I assume you are not rooted, if you were any number of apps could likely do this such as Titanium Backup, but if not Android 4.x was weird with SD card permissions and many functions like that could be only be done by the system and not a 3rd party app

Comment: Yeah, not rooted. Having trouble rooting my phone [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173231/cant-find-option-install-zip-from-sd-card-after-installing-clockworkmod). I can't install SuperSU.

Comment: Without root it's one at a time... Sorry.

Comment: Okay, no problem. Add an answer if you like.

Comment: Also be aware some apps cannot be moved to the SD card; but some of those apps can store _data_ for the app on the SD card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving apps to the SD card in bulk requires root, with root access apps like Titanium Backup should be able to move them easily. Otherwise you must move them individually.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Mario's answer](https://forums.androidcentral.com/showthread.php?t=663165&p=5722424&viewfull=1#post5722424):

There is an easier way than manually finding and moving one by one. I'm aware it's no bulk, but it helps.

[App2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd)

It helps to find all movable apps, and gets you to the move screen one by one, after you perform the move (manually), also instructing on impacts for each app.

Answer (score 2):

2022 update: [App2 SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd) finds all apps that can be moved from device to SD. The app has an automatic mode for then moving all these apps to SD card (via Android accessibility tools, easy to use).

[image: Screenshot of App2SD's bulk move-to-SD function]