# Can't find option ‘Install zip from SD card’ after installing Clockworkmod

Tags: rooting

I'm following [this guide](https://support.digitalendpoint.com/hc/en-us/articles/204812787-How-to-root-the-HTC-Desire-510) to root my HTC Desire 510.

I reach the step **Step 4 – Root the HTC Desire 510**.

I perform the command `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img` in a cmd prompt, and I receive the message:

```
sending 'recovery' (10594 KB)...
OKAY [1.352s]
writing 'recovery'....
OKAY [0.731s]
finished. total time 2.085s
```

I rebooted my phone, then powered off the phone.

At **Step 5 – Install SuperSU**, I don't see the option **‘Install zip from SD card’**. I don't see **Install Zip** either.

This is what I see:

```
FASTBOOT
RECOVERY
FACTORY RESET
SIMLOCK
CHECK SMARTSD
IMAGE CRC
SHOW BARCODE
```

What do I need to do to Install SuperSU?

Help appreciated.

Comment: The guide seems very incomplete... I'll try to find a better guide and post a link shortly.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/desire-510/general/guide-how-to-unlock-install-recovery-t2988292

Comment: Also, to start the recovery you flashed, select Recovery with the Vol Up/Down buttons and press Power to start it.

Answer (score 0):

FASTBOOT REBOOT RECOVERY
ONE THAT RE STARTS

`adb usb`

`adb devices`

`adb -s sideload nameofzip.zip`

(-s is the serial # of device)

Comment: After `adb usb` I receive `error: no devices/emulators found`. The phone is connected on USB okay.

Comment: try adb kill-server then run adb usb again

Comment: I should have of this right away but its 7 in the morning here

Comment: Same error after `adb kill-server` then run `adb usb` again.

Comment: do you have google hangout? add me on there ill help you get this resolved and also you running windows adb or Linux?

Comment: Thanks for carrying this conversation to another venue. Don't forget to update this answer with the relevant steps or changes that would benefit all readers.

Comment: I forgot to enable debugging on the mobile. Now, I run the command `adb -CCXXXXXXX sideload UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.16.zip` and I receive a help output, basically explaining how to use the `adb` command, but not giving a specific error message.

Comment: How do I add you on Google Hangout? I'm using Windows ADB.

Comment: sign into google via internet explore then go into hangouts add my email
reaverdroiddeveloper@gmail.com